# Send a challenge to another player without a service component in android

Tags: android, communication

Scenario : Let us say, I finished a puzzle game in x amount of time. I want to challenge one of my friend to beat that time. Let us say there is a way to send a request(sms, email, Fb link) with game parameters, when my friend clicks on the request game starts with specified settings. Then my friend can notify me if he beat me.

Can this be designed without any server/service component and just by using available communication methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes, you could just have a custom link like so

```
mygame://start?gametype=type&timetobeat=430&moredata=data
```

You can use an intent-filter to capture custom URLs like the one above

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="mygame" android:host="start" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Just capture the parameters and use those to start the game. It's not a recommended way to do this as using a server would probably be best. It's also not difficult to change those parameters and cause the game to load up with some ridiculous parameters so be careful in what you allow in from the user

Comment: Is there a way to avoid modifications of parameters using encryption.?

Is adding this text in sms or email body is sufficient to open up my application if its installed?